# Connect iPhone and Android devices (same LAN)

Tags: android, ios, tcpclient, tcpserver

I would like to exchange information between two or more devices (Android and/or iOS).

All the devices will be connected by WIFI to the same Router.

- Is it possible to make direct (client/server) TCP/IP connection in iPhone and Android?
- And how can I automatically "discover" the other devices on the network? Should I scan all the IP range (example 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255) for the given port ?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to develop using [Xamarin.iOS](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) and [Xamarion.Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) you could consider using the network library [NetworkComms.Net](http://www.networkcomms.net/features/) (which uses [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) under the hood) to quickly add the the functionality you are looking for. Example iOS and Android applications are provided.

Device discovery would be achieved using the included [UDP broadcast](http://www.networkcomms.net/udp-broadcasting/) support.

Disclaimer: Although I think this is a good fit for your problem I have to add that I am a developer for NetworkComms.Net.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that @Wain is referring to Bonjour (on iOS), which is an Apple implementation of the Zeroconf protocol.

For Android, have a look at jmDNS - see  http://android.noisepages.com/2010/02/yes-android-can-do-zeroconfbonjour-jmdns/

There's an example of using it [here](https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo/)

Comment: It is written that jmdns is fully compatible Apple's Bonjour, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mDNSResponder` to allow the different decides to discover each other and connect.